# Broken files after download from server PHP

Tags: php, download, torrent

i have script to download torrent files from server:

```
header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Cache-Control: private");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Type: application/x-bittorrent");
        header('Content-Length: '.filesize($local));
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$local."\"");
        $file = fopen($local, "r");
        print fread($file, filesize($local));
        fclose($file);
```

And if i download file, torrent is broken and cant to use, anyone can help me ?
The error is :

> Torrent file decoding failed! Please try to re-download the torrent!

**EDIT:**

```
$path = 'torrent/'; 
$local = $path.$row['file_src'];
```

I make little changes

```
header('Cache-control: private');
    header('Content-Type: application/x-bittorrent');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($local));
    header('Content-Disposition: filename='.$download);
    $file = fopen($local, "r"); 
    print fread($file, filesize($local)); 
    fclose($file);
```

**EDIT:**
Sorry but generaly its not problem with this thanks @deceze, problem is in torrent file, After download has one line down. How i can repair this ?

Comment: What does "torrent is broken" mean? What does the file contain? Show us! Or is it just that the torrent is not available any more?

Comment: Torrent file decoding failed! Please try to re-download the torrent!

Comment: can you confirm that all your headers are correct? your expires value could be a value > 0 but below time? You also need to use different quotes on your final `header` line as the header is wrapped in `"` but your filename needs to be wrapped in `'` quotes rather than more ".

Comment: i maked little changes header('Cache-control: private');
  header('Content-Type: application/x-bittorrent');
  header('Content-Length: '.filesize($local));
  header('Content-Disposition: filename='.$download);
  $file = fopen($local, "r"); // otwieramy nasz lokalny plik
  print fread($file, filesize($local)); // wrzucamy do przeglÄ…darki odczyt, czyli wywoĹ‚ujemy Ĺ›ciÄ…gniÄ™cie
  fclose($file);

Comment: My question was: what does the downloaded file contain. not what happens if you double click it. Why can't you simply look in there? And see what's up?

Comment: Seriously: just open the downloaded file in a text editor/hex editor and **look at it**. Compare with the original. Figure out what's different.

Comment: now i see, after download from my site, torrent file has one line down gyazo.com/30a19d0c4917c83e2b50a3444f9d5ca7

Answer (score -1):

```
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$local."\"");
```

this line is an issue, because your header text is wrapped in `"` but your filename sub-part is also wrapped in `"` so the code will not understand two layers using the same quotes, so instead change it to:

```
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='".$local."'");
```

This maintains the quote structure of the header.

Comment: if i use your method, filename is 'file.torrent'

Comment: well what is the value of `$local`, it is not set in your code exampled @MaxFosterr

Comment: $path = 'torrent/';
$local = $path.$row['file_src'];

Comment: That's what the ``\`` are for, there is no issue here.

Comment: yeah @deceze well pointed out. I reread my post and can't believe I misread that. poo :(